# Mono not delaying

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've got the following piece of code, which I thought would delay the mono, I'm simply trying to do retry with a backoff interval

```
    private Mono<ThreeDSServerRedisDto> loadRedisDtoAndRetry(FrictionlessInfo frictionlessInfo, long retryNumber) {
        int maxRetries = 10;
        if (retryNumber >= maxRetries) {
            log.info("Unable to load the data after {} attempts aborting", maxRetries);
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        long delayFactor = (long) (Math.pow(retryNumber, 2)*20L);
        if (retryNumber > 0 ){
            log.info("Load data attempt {}, delayFactor {}s", retryNumber, delayFactor);
        }
        return Mono
                .delay(Duration.ofSeconds(delayFactor))
                .then(threeDSRedisService.loadByToken(frictionlessInfo.getThreeDSv2Token()))
                .switchIfEmpty(loadRedisDtoAndRetry(frictionlessInfo, retryNumber + 1));
    }
```

However it doesn't appear to be delaying anything at all.

The sanitized logs look like this.

```
2020-08-04 17:14:02,957 [ -  - ] INFO - Load data attempt 1, delayFactor 20s
2020-08-04 17:14:02,958 [ -  - ] INFO - Load data attempt 2, delayFactor 80s
...
...
2020-08-04 17:14:02,963 [ -  - ] INFO - Load data attempt 9, delayFactor 1620s
2020-08-04 17:14:02,964 [ -  - ] INFO - Unable to load the data  after 10 attempts aborting
```

Now my maths may be wrong but 7ms **is probably shorter than** 1620s. Why doesn't the delay occur and what is the best way to try again with exponential back off when the mono is empty.

Comment: i think `retryWhen` is what you are looking for https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry- in combination with `Retry.backOff` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/Retry.html#backoff-long-java.time.Duration- i have never used them but according to API that might be what you are looking for

Comment: the method calls within the `.then()` and `.switchIfEmpty()` will be invoked at assembly time not at the point of subscription. This means the delay won't take any effect. Wrapping both in Mono.defer might give you functionality you desire though there are probably better ways of doing it as Thomas has mentioned above.